# soup.select css nth of type?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to select the 2nd column of the following html with beautiful soup

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="column">
      <div class="inventory">1</div>
      <div class="inventory">2</div>
      <div class="inventory">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
      <div class="inventory">4</div>
      <div class="inventory">5</div>
      <div class="inventory">6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
      <div class="inventory">7</div>
      <div class="inventory">8</div>
      <div class="inventory">9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using the css idiom `div.column + div` to select the 2nd column.  However the below iterates over the rows in both the 2nd and 3rd column.  I believe the logic `div.column + div` isn't doing what I expect it to.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlSource)
secondColumn = soup.select('div.column + div div.inventory')
for row in column:
    #prints stuff about the row
```

Is there any way I can only iterate over the rows of the 2nd column?

Comment: The output is entirely correct for the given CSS; both the second and third `div` are directly following a `<div class="column">` element.

Comment: Oh my misunderstanding - How do i specifically select only the 2nd column?

Comment: Is there any way to select the *parent* div more easily? Otherwise your options are limited and require more code to avoid duplicates.

Comment: So you want to extract the `4`, `5` and `6` inventory divs, right?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - yes, please see my updated question for the class added to the parent to make the parent more easy to select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resultset is entirely correct for the given CSS; the third `div` follows a div with the `column` class *too* (the second div has that class, after all).

You'll have to find *all* `column` divs and just pick out the second one from that result set:

```
soup.select("div > div.column")[1]
```

This'll only give you the one column, even if there are more such groups elsewhere in the document.

If you need the second column *per parent*, add a loop:

```
for parent in soup.select('div.parent'):
    column = parent.select('div.column')[1]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <div class="parent">
...   <div class="column">
...       <div class="inventory">1</div>
...       <div class="inventory">2</div>
...       <div class="inventory">3</div>
...   </div>
...   <div class="column">
...       <div class="inventory">4</div>
...       <div class="inventory">5</div>
...       <div class="inventory">6</div>
...   </div>
...   <div class="column">
...       <div class="inventory">7</div>
...       <div class="inventory">8</div>
...       <div class="inventory">9</div>
...   </div>
... </div>
... ''')
>>> soup.select("div.parent > div.column")[1]
<div class="column">
<div class="inventory">4</div>
<div class="inventory">5</div>
<div class="inventory">6</div>
</div>
>>> for parent in soup.select('div.parent'):
...     column = parent.select('div.column')[1]
...     print column
... 
<div class="column">
<div class="inventory">4</div>
<div class="inventory">5</div>
<div class="inventory">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`BeautifulSoup` supports css classes directly:

```
for parent in soup.find_all('div', 'parent'):
    second_column = parent('div', 'column')[1]
    # handle the second column
```